# Help ubuntu sound issuse's (14.4)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I am really new to Ubuntu. I have version 14.04 and I have been having a tonne of problems with sound; my issues are:

- There are no sound drivers showing up on system menu.
- When I get sound to work (I can hear clicking as I turn up and down the volume) it doesn't play on videos.
- I know that Ubuntu recognizes my drivers but nothing happens in the system menu and I get no sound.

I have tried many solutions but one solution has only worked once at a time. I have tried:

- uninstalling pulseaudio (and re-installing): when I do this options disappear from the system settings menu and when I fix it the sound problem is back
- changing drivers
- force reloading alsa
- alsamixer
- many others that I can't even remember.

If I connect it to a HDMI cable I get image and sound and something shows up in settings(hdmi).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: Does sound work correctly when using HDMI?  If yes, did you change the output by clicking on let's say internal speakers and clicking "test sound"?

Comment: It works fine when using HDMI and no I did not change the output (it was the only one that showed up)

Comment: So you don't see anything like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YDFeB.png)? Only HDMI output?  Please then do a `hardinfo --generate-report --load-module computer.so --load-module devices.so > /tmp/HardInfo.txt` and upload `/tmp/HardInfo.txt` to paste.ubuntu.com and provide the link back...  :-)

Comment: Somehow I have found a fix (upon boot there is nothing listed in devices), if I have something playing in chrome and then I "sudo alsa force-reload" then it works (there is no hdmi output device, it only shows when I plug it in).
Here is the output -> http://paste.ubuntu.com/10356878/

Comment: If that fixes your problem, could you add that as an answer so  that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 0):

Copied answer from comments:

Somehow I have found a fix (upon boot there is nothing listed in devices):

If I have something playing in chrome and then I `sudo alsa force-reload` then it works (there is no hdmi output device, it only shows when I plug it in)